# Scala Function to replace column value in DataFrame1 if null with DataFrame2 value

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark

I have 100 columns in DataFrame1 and 100 columns in DataFrame2
now I want to replace null values in DataFrame1 for all the columns with DataFrame2 column values. If DataFrame2 value is also null then use DataFrame1 value.

Note: Both DataFrame1 and DataFrame2 have same column names.

I have solution when I select each column in a dataframe but I'm looking for a general function where I can apply for all the columns in a dataframe.

I tried the following but this is for one column only but I want to use this function for all the columns in a dataframe:

```
val df5 = Seq((1, null), (2, "B")).toDF("id", "colA")
val df6 = Seq((1, "C"), (4, "D")).toDF("id", "colA")
```

```
+---+----+
| id|colA|
+---+----+ --> df5.show
|  1|null|
|  2|   B|
+---+----+

+---+----+
| id|colA|
+---+----+
|  1|   C| --> df6.show
|  4|   D|
+---+----+
```

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def replaceNull(A:DataFrame, B:DataFrame) :DataFrame = {
  A.join(B, Seq("id"), "left")
   .withColumn("colA", when(A("colA").isNull, B("colA")).otherwise(A("colA")))  
}
replaceNull(df5, df6).show
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+
| id|colA|colA|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   C|   C|
|  2|   B|   B|
+---+----+----+
```

Also this results in duplicate column (in this case - colA is seen two times) but I would like to see only one time i.e from left table.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The slightly modified code:

```
df_temp = A.join(B, Seq("id"), "left").withColumn("temp_col", when(A("colA").isNull, B("colA")).otherwise(A("colA"))).drop("colA")
df = df_temp.withColumnRenamed("temp_col", "colA")

df.show
+---+----+
| id|colA|
+---+----+
|  1|   C|
|  2|   B|
+---+----+
```

Alternative:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val columns = df1.columns.intersect(df2.columns).map(col)
val df_temp = df1.join(df2, Seq("id"), "outer").select(columns.map(col_name => coalesce(df1(col_name), df2(col_name)).alias(col_name)): _*)
df_temp.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @ASR.Your solution works for replacing 1 column in  dataFrame1 from dataFrame2 and remove the duplicate column created.
I'm looking for a general function to replace null values for all the columns in dataFrame1 from dataFrame2.

Comment: Updated the answer for any number of columns, but this will be very expensive.